# Why can a constant not be empty checked?

Tags: php, constants, is-empty

Why does

```
if (!empty(constant('MY_CONST')))
```

throw this error

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context
```

and how do I work around it?

Comment: maybe you want if(!defined("MY_CONST"))...

Comment: @steven No I don't, I really want to check if it has a proper value.

Comment: `Constant()` returns the value of the constant defined by some name which is passed to the `Constant()` function. I guess you havent defined any constant`s against **MY_CONST**.REF:http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the note [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

So you should rather compare against `null` as [`constant()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) will return `null` for undefined constants, or use [`defined()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) instead.

```
if(constant('MY_CONST')!==null) { ... }
if(!defined('MY_CONST')) { ... }
```

Comment: That's a shame. Here's what I did now: `function ConstEmpty($name) { $value = constant($name); return empty($value); }` Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 2):

With PHP 5.5.0 your code will work as is. However, you can simply break your statement into 2 pieces for backward compatibility.

```
$a = constant('MY_CONST');
if(!empty($a)) { //do something }
```

Alternatively, you can use the `defined()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to implementation details in PHP: until PHP 5.4.x, only variables can be tested using `empty()`.

What you're trying to do will likely work in php 5.5. Alternatively, use:

```
if (defined('CONST') && CONST)
```

Answer (score 0):

empty() can only be used to check variables. See the php manual. You can use defined.

```
if (defined('TEST')) {
    echo TEST;
}
```